# How to remove jQuery UI sortable from an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am binding sortable to an element like so:

```
$('#elem').sortable({
   items: 'li',
   placeholder: 'drop-highlight',
   forcePlaceholderSize: true,
   revert: true
});
```

On a certain event I want to no longer allow this element to be sortable. How do I unbind it?

All these were tried individually and all failed (i.e. #elem was still sortable afterwards):

```
$('#elem').unbind('sort');
$('#elem').sortable('destroy');
$('#elem').sortable('option', 'sort', null);
```

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as a duplicate, it shouldn't be. This question is about reversing whatever $.fn.sortable does to an element. The "duplicate" is about preventing a child element from being sorted. Two different questions.

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, it su**s :-( this removes the functionality *and* the css classes / injected spans after 1 sec (destroy appearently just kill the widget, not the added classes or tags)

```
$('#elem').sortable({
   items: 'li',
   placeholder: 'drop-highlight',
   forcePlaceholderSize: true,
   revert: true
});
```

place this code in a handler when you need to "unsortable" the list

```
function() {
    $("#elem").sortable("destroy"); //call widget-function destroy
    $("#elem li").removeClass('ui-state-default');
    $("#elem li span").remove();
}
```

$("#elem").sortable("destroy"); *does* actually destroy the sortable functionality, it just forget to clean up.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to disable the sortable then try this:

```
$("#elem").sortable("disable");
```

and to enable back

```
$("#elem").sortable("enable" );
```

Comment: pass destory in sortable somthing like below